# Echo array value three levels deep (acf and wordpress)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get some values from the post_objects array produced when using ACF http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

This is the array I have:

```
Array ( [team_member] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 57 [post_author] => 2 [post_date] => 2015-05-26 14:41:04 [post_date_gmt] => 2015-05-26 14:41:04 [post_content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illa tamen simplicia, vestra versuta. In his igitur partibus duabus nihil erat, quod Zeno commutare gestiret. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Idcirco enim non desideraret, quia, quod dolore caret, id in volupta [post_title] => Jeffery Simms [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => jeffery-simms [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2015-05-26 14:41:04 [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-05-26 14:41:04 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://mbp.local:5757/?post_type=team_members&p=57 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => team_members [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) )
```

I am looking for th epost title to start with but will need the featured image also.  I tried to echo the desired value like this:

```
<?php echo$team_members[0][team_member][post_title]; ?>
```

But I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Well your echo has to space after it.

Comment: This is PHP 101 how to access an object property; how to access an array index

Comment: Why people don't read error message anymore? It says exactly what the problem is: you cannot use an object as an array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access object properties use `->` instead of `[]`.

Comment: amazing... I have been using all manner of combinations to get at that =>, is obviously wrong.  :)